# Is it possible to update or remove IEndpointRouteBuilder existing route entries

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I'm trying to handle this error in asp.net core 5

`AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches`

if possible, by removing previously register route (nopcommerce) but seems like there's no method or clean and easy work around available.

So, i'm wondering if there's any way to do something like
`endpointRouteBuilder.AddOrUpdateControllerRoute` or `endpointRouteBuilder.RemoveRouteEntry` and then register new one

Comment: which route you are trying to override?

Comment: catalog/autocompletesearch (without renaming url or routename itself)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091247/remove-route-from-routecollection-in-asp-net-core-and-add-new-with-same-route-na

You can try the last option